# maven-jaxb2-plugin not generating sources

Tags: maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

It would be great if someone could help me with this. I am new to Maven. When executing generate-sources or compile Maven is quiet about it and nothing gets generated.

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>jaxb-test</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                  <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                  <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>sample.xsd</include>
                  </schemaIncludes>
                  <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `build/plugins`, not `build/plugins/pluginManagement`.

Please refer to the exact duplicate:

[maven goal doesn't execute properly if plugins are defined under pluginManagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115454/maven-goal-doesnt-execute-properly-if-plugins-are-defined-under-pluginmanagemen)